# Orderby statement uses First() method call, why is it needed?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I'm new to Linq and I'm wondering why the **First()** method call is needed when ordering by the County in the following query.  Also, after knowing *why* it is needed, could the same result be accomplished by using the **Last()** method?

```
var hsQ = from hspt in hospitals
          orderby hspt.City
          group hspt by hspt.County into hsptGroup
          orderby hsptGroup.First().County
          select hsptGroup;
```

Note:  The above example is part of a Question/Answer from a book I'm reading, and the type *hospitals* is not defined explicitly for me to see.

Comment: It would have been clearer if they'd used the `.Key` of the group in the `orderby` since the `Key` in this case is the County.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `hsptGroup` holds a group of hospitals, not a single hospital.

Even though all the hospitals in this group have the same county, you still need to specify `.First()`, so you can reference a single hospital's county.

Comment: It would help to note that all hospitals within that group have the same value for `Country` since they were all grouped by that property.  So ordering by any of these hospitals by `Country`, whether it is the `First()` or `Last()` will yield the same result.  As Hightechrider mentions in his comment, it would be clearest if the `hsptGroup` was ordered by the `Key`.

Comment: So the point of the First() method is to get a single value to order by?  Does it depend what the county is that First().Count receives?  I.e. If the county starts with A or Z, is it relevant?

Comment: @contactmatt `.First()` returns the first hospital record for every group. Why would you be calling `.First().Count`?

Comment: Ah, "`County`", I fell for it too.  I blame that on Scrum.  :)

Comment: Thanks Gabe, i guess burning the midnight oil has some side affects :-)

Comment: @The Scrum Meister Ah sorry, meant to say First().County.  Not count, "county" :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually that First is used to access First Element in the Collection of items Grouped. So subsequently the ordering is done on the basis of the First Item's County. Yes you can do Last and that way ordering will be done on the basis of last item in the Grouped Collection.